# Dicom Image Reader custom S-Block in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am working on a project related to image processing. I want to create a level-2 S-block in simulink for reading Dicom Images (.dcm). There should be a browse button and edit text section in the Dialog box. Whenever i click on the browse button image can be selected and the path of that image should be displayed on the edit parameter. Any idea what should be the mask callback functions for these parameters. Here is a sample callback for mask parameters. [See Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufcI9.jpg)

```
function DicomReader_callback(action,block)

feval(action,block)

function pushbutton_callback(block)

[fn pn] = uigetfile('*.dcm','select dicom file');
complete = strcat(pn,fn);
get_param(gcb, 'UserData');
set_param(gcb, 'UserData', complete);
function edit_callback(block)
```

Thanks !

Comment: This is a very broad question. Maybe provide a little more information on what you've implemented so far, attach some code, and highlight the *specific* part that you're having issues with. Then maybe we can provide you with some help.

Comment: I have uploaded a piece of code and a sample image.

Comment: Have you tried setting the callback property with your code in the property editor section?

Comment: yes i did try. The problem is,  i am able to load the file by pressing the push button but i want to show the full path in the edit section parameter. so that i can use that path as a dialog parameter in my original s-function.

Comment: Thanx everyone. I made it :)